# Erro com AutoComplete jquery UI

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, autocompletar

Boa tarde, estou recebendo um erro que particularmente eu nunca vi, ao tentar usar o autocomplete do jquery, segue a imagem, e a codificação:

[image: Imagem do erro:]

PHP: (usei como exemplo, pois não adicionei o like no select, são valores dinâmicos!

```
    <?php

 require_once('acessabanco.php');

 $objDb = new db();
 $link = $objDb->conecta_banco();

 $sql = "SELECT p.sequencia codigo,
                p.nome_completo nome, 
                c.data_nascimento data, 
                t.celular_1 celular
           FROM pessoas p, 
                clientes c, 
                telefones t 
          WHERE p.sequencia = t.cod_pessoa 
            AND c.cod_pessoa = p.sequencia";
 $exec = mysqli_query($link, $sql);     
 if ($exec){
    while ($clientes = mysqli_fetch_array($exec)){
        $vetor[] = array('Sequencia' => $clientes['codigo'], 'Nome' => $clientes['nome']);
    }
    echo json_encode($vetor);
}
```

JQUERY:

```
 $.getJSON("php/lista_clientes.php", function(data){
    var teste = [];
    $(data).each(function(key, value){

        teste.push(value.Nome);
    });
});

  $( "#buscar_cliente" ).autocomplete({
    source: teste
  });
```

Está me retornando o erro acima.. OBS: Se eu usar o exemplo do próprio site do jquery, ele funciona normalmente, porem quando eu busco os dados do banco ele me exibe isso..

Caso alguém saiba do que se trata, ficarei muito grato se ajudar!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Coloque o:

```
$( "#buscar_cliente" ).autocomplete({
   source: teste
});
```

Dentro da função que carrega o JSON:

```
$.getJSON("conecta.php", function(data){
   var teste = [];
   $(data).each(function(key, value){

      teste.push(value.Nome);
   });

   $( "#buscar_cliente" ).autocomplete({
      source: teste
   });
});
```

Colocando fora, a variável `var teste` não será reconhecida porque ainda não foi definida no `.autocomplete`.

Comment: Deu certo!! Muito obrigado pela sua ajuda!